# Refresh listbox with inserted value

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want the easiest way to refresh my ListBox when value is inserted

And then we have the create a new company code, I want the listbox to be updated once thus code is runned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list portion of your `ListBox` is data bound, the easiest way to show the newly added company name (without rebuilding the whole list) is to add it to the underlying data source, and the data binding infrastructure will take care of updating the `ListBox` for you:

```
private void createCompany_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    ((DataTable)companyList.DataSource).Rows.Add(textBoxCompanyName.Text);
}
```

Comment: So slick, so cleaver and so little code. The perfect answer :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hi call this method after Message box(MessageBox.Show("Grattis! Du har skapat ett företag");).

initCompanyList();